# Socket io delay one event

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I have connected socket io to Webhook and it succeeds. It can get information and can express But I'm stuck with one problem. When the desired value is displayed on the client-side, the response is delayed. For example, when the server-side detects an event will show on console.log(); But it won't show on the client-side. But when the server-side detects the event again (second time) The value saved the first time is sent to the client-side, and if the server detects the event again (third time) The second event value is sent to the client-side, which means it will delay the event one time. How can I fix this incident?

```js
// Server
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io', { 
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'] 
})(http, {
    cors: {
        origin:'*'
    }
});
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


PORT = 8080;

io.on('connection', socket => {
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/api', (req, res) => {
 
    let x = req.body[0];
    let dates = x.created_date; 
    let name = x.name; 
    let watchlist = x.watchlist[Object];

if (watchlist == "Matched"){
  console.log("Date :", dates)
  console.log("Name :", name)
  io.emit('FromAPI', dates, name);
}
else {
  console.log("Unmatch")
}
res.status(200).end("Successfully");
    
});
console.log('Socket connected');
socket.on('disconnect', () => { console.log('Socket disconnected')});
});

http.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server : http://localhost: ${PORT}`);
});
```

```js
// Client
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io("http://localhost:8080", { transports: ['websocket', 'polling'] });


export default function App() {
   const [date, setDate] = useState('');
   const [name, setName] = useState('');
   const [hook_event, setHook_event] = useState([
     { "date": date, "name": name},
     { "date": date, "name": name}
   ]);
   
  
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('FromAPI', (date, name) => {
      setDate(date);
      setName(name);

      hook_event.unshift({"date": date, "name": name});
      hook_event.pop();
    })
  }, [];

  return (
    <>      
       <p>Date : {hook_event[0].date} and {hook_event[0].name}</p>
       <p>Date : {hook_event[1].date} and {hook_event[1].name}</p>
    </> 
  );
};
```

Comment: Instead of `show_event.unshift` and `show_event.pop` try to use `setShow_event([{ "name": name, "age": age }, show_event[0]])`

Comment: Thank you so much I will try, I am very new to React and NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem.

```
    const [countState, setCountState] = useState() 

    useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('FromAPI', (date, name) => {
      setDate(date);
      setName(name);

      hook_event.unshift({"date": date, "name": name});
      hook_event.pop();
      setCountState(hook_event[0])
    })
    }, [setCountState]; // update setCountState
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).