# How can I solve this problem? : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUF

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, react-hooks

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUF
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you explain more to understand why are you getting this problem? If possible share codebase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69403402/socket-io-delay-one-event This was my prior problem. I use this code.